# How to find x-way intersection in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Can SQL INTERSECT keyword be used to find an x-way intersection?

SELECT col FROM tab 1
INTERSECT
SELECT col FROM tab 2
INTERSECT
SELECT col FROM tab 3

Or am I better off just using an x-way INNER JOIN?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "x-way intersection", it's not a technical term. Consider providing sample input tables and expected output, you query (if any) for what you're attempting to do.

Comment: I’m attempting to find the values which are present in every table listed. So to return a value in col,  that value must be present in tab1, tab2 & tab3.

Comment: Or another way, what’s the intersection of multiple sets? Aka what intersect is supposed to mean

Comment: Intersection is exactly what you described in your first comment. The mathematical definition applies to databases as well, where the elementary unit is the record.